# Using cardano-cli with a Daedalus wallet

Tags: daedalus, cardano-cli

I want to be able to use a wallet that I have on Daedalus, but to mint some tokens. The README on cardano-cli is outdated, and obviously not working and couldn't find an up-to-date instructions to import mnemonic seed using cardano-cli.

From https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-cli/blob/master/USAGE.md:

> Recovering a Daedalus wallet
>
> For various reasons the CLI does not allow to create Daedalus
> compatible wallet. But it is possible to recover a wallet created on
> the Daedalus application.
>
> cardano-cli wallet recover --daedalus-seed --derivation-scheme=v1
> --mnemonics-length=12 --wallet-scheme=random_index_2levels MyDaedalusWallet
>
> And that's it, you will your daedalus wallet recovered here. No need to transfer the funds to another address yet (and therefor save some transaction fees).

cardano-wallet doesn't seem to have any of those options, or at least, a resemblance of those steps

Comment: What is your motivation for using Daedalus keys, rather than creating a new keys/address with `cardano-cli` for minting?

Comment: ease-of-use when sending the tokens :)

Comment: Good point, but you could send the newly minted tokens to your Daedalus addresses from the cli. Working with Daedalus keys on command line does not sound like fun, or at worst a security risk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [cardano-address cli tool](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. too bad the official docs is like a maze of outdated links